# create a uniform scrolling speed on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

let's say I have a page with a lot of things on it at different areas.

I want to make an event which will scroll the page down to it, at a certain "rate". However, the method I am using seems very inconsistent. It takes the same amount of time to scroll to an element a few pixels from the navbar as it does to scroll to the very end of the page

```
$('.slide-to').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).data('element')).offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

How can this be modified to make a "uniform" scroll speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to modify the duration (currently 2000 ms) to reflect the amount of pixels that need to be scrolled.

```
$('.slide-to').click(function() {
    elemY = $($(this).data('element')).offset().top;
    pixels = Math.abs($(window).scrollTop() - elemY);
    pixelsPerMs = 10; 
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: elemY
    }, pixelsPerMs * pixels);
});
```

You might also want to change the easing function of the animation.

Comment: this one helped, and I found it to be the easiest to read. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're able to do that and I've created a working example that can be found here http://jsbin.com/jociy/3

In case you're wondering, I've also left a few comments and I think the code is self explanatory and here it goes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Say you're happy with scrolling 100px during 2secs
 var height = 100;
 var secs = 2000;

 // Calculate the ratio
 var ratio = (secs / height);

 // Now use the ratio to calculate new time according to container height
 var time = ratio * $(window).height();

 $('#scrollTo').on('click', function(){

    // get the element position that you want to scroll to
    var toPosition = $(".scrollTo").offset().top;

    // scroll to the element position
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: toPosition
    }, time, "linear");

 });

});
```

A few things to notice, that are extremely useful for what you want to achieve:

1) You're able to create the desired speed, by testing the amount of seconds in a given distance, by using this as a reference you can find a speed that you like. You decide the best speed!

2) In the example, I've used "linear" ease function, to keep everything clear and basic for you. I would advice using something more neat, but again, you have control as you wish!

That's all! Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the animation duration proportional to the distance between you current position and the position of the element you want to scroll to, you can try this:

```
$('.slide-to').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).data('element')).offset().top
  }, Math.abs($($(this).data('element')).offset().top - this.offset().top) * 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the value of `$(this).data('element')).offset().top` as your timer value and then just multiply it by a multiplier to get how many pixels per milisecond you want the scroll to animate. Then increase the multiplier to slow down the animation.

```
$('.slide-to').click(function() {
  var multiplier = 10;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).data('element')).offset().top
  }, $(this).data('element')).offset().top * multiplier);
});
```